# How do I calculate the maximum frequency?

Tags: vlsi

How could I calculate this questions? Would you please let me know?

[image]

Given the above design,reference the figure

1.What are the effective setup and hold times between IN and CLK in the above circuit?

2.What is the maximum operating frequency of the above circuit?

Would you please let me know the reason of why not just answer?

I think that the first answer is delay 1ns + Tclk->Q 4ns = 5ns.

and second answer is 1/5ns = 200Mhz.

but What do I wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework without any effort shown in solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterJ No, this is not home work. Please help and let me know how do I calculate for Max Frequescy.

Comment: How do you know your answer is wrong?  ("but What do I wrong?")

Answer (score 6):

We don't just answer homework for you here.

First, do you understand what setup and hold times mean?  If not, look those up.

One way to solve this is to draw a timing diagram with CLK transitioning from low to high at T=0.  Now work thru the delays to make the CLK signal as seen by the flip flop, then show the range of time over which the D input to the flip flop must be steady for it to be interpreted correctly.  Now project that time range backwards thru the external delays to get the time range OUT must be solid over.

Once you know when OUT must be steady relative to CLK, you can look at how long you have to wait between successive CLK pulses.  The reciprocal of that is the maximum frequency this system can be clocked at.

Answer (score 2):

You should make a timing diagram showing all of the signal edges with the minimum allowed time between them. Once you do that, the minimum period of the clock will be defined and its maximum frequency will be that period's reciprocal.

Answer (score 1):

To find the max freq, calculate the longest output path delay. Here it is:
 Tclk2q + Txor + Tsu - Tskew = 4 + 2 + 2 - 1 = 7ns.

Max freq of operation = 1/7ns = 142.857 MHz

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know Max setup and Max hold.
the Max setup is considered like this 2 case.

## 1.clock delay help setup time.

## 2.the data arrives more quick.

So Ts = Tffs+Tinv-Txor =1

Also max hold is vice versa.
Th = Tffs-Tinv+Txor = 3